# How to share dynamic link via Facebook without FB SDK

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I've tried to share firebase dynamic link

```
final Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");

    final String link = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vizumlab.vizuminfo";

    FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
            .setLink(Uri.parse(String.format("https://vizum.page.link/?link=%s&msgid=%s", link, id)))
            .setAndroidParameters(new DynamicLink.AndroidParameters.Builder("com.vizumlab.vizuminfo").setFallbackUrl(Uri.parse(link)).build())
            .setDynamicLinkDomain("vizum.page.link")
            .buildShortDynamicLink()
            .addOnSuccessListener(l -> {
                        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, activity.getString(R.string.message_share_format_text, name,
                                "https://vizum.page.link?link=" + link + "&apn=com.vizumlab.vizuminfo&ofl=https://vizuminfo.com"));
                        activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, activity.getString(R.string.message_share)));
                        ReceiverBus.INSTANCE.notify(R.id.code_show_loader, false);
                    }
            )
```

Works totally fine everywhere except FB.
[image]

On tap:
[image]

Does anybode know how to solve this?

**UPD:**

this code for dynamic link creating is not suitable for FB too

```
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, activity.getString(R.string.message_share_format_text, name, l.getShortLink().toString()));
```

Comment: What would *Tap for more info* say? Any errors on logcat or any helpful thing?

Comment: Edited post, added screenshot. No errors on logcat. As I said - it works totally well everywhere except FB

Comment: When put one URL into another URL as a parameter value, then you should always URL-encode it properly.

Comment: What do you mean? Is there some problem with encoding? I updated question. Tried to create link another way - with the same result

Comment: Could you paste in a link that fails?

Comment: https://vizum.page.link/X57R8qDi1TLosqxi6 for example